# Why does chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() return null?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a **manifest.json** file that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Zend Debugger Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Launch Zend Debugger",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Here's my **background.html**:

```
<html>
    <script>
    function testRequest() {
        console.log("test Request received");
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

And my **popup.html**:

```
<script>
function debug(target) {
    if (target.id == 'thisPage') {
        console.log('sending request');
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().testRequest();
    }
}
</script>

<div onclick="debug(this)" id="thisPage">Current Page</div>
```

However, the **background.html** page doesn't seem to be accessible. I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'testRequest' of null
```

When I inspect `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` I get a null value. I'm thinking I have made a mistake in my manifest file, but I can't see what I've done wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing the background permission, take a look at my manifest.json file of my chrome extension:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "asserts.js"]
    }
  ],
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A test extension to inject js to a webpage.",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_url>", "background"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**
Are you sure you have the `background.html` file on the same folder as all your chrome-extension's files?, and if so, try reloading your extension from the extension management page, I remember once had a bug that my extension didn't reload, so I went to the developer's tools for my background page and executed `window.location.reload(true);` from console, that fixed it. Please respond if this worked, I will keep researching

Comment: I tried adding the background permission but still get null when trying chrome.extension.getBackground() and the same error when the script runs. I actually thought the background permission related to whether the extension still runs in the background when all tabs are closed: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Comment: Are you sure you have the background.html file on the same folder as all your chrome-extension's files?, and if so, try reloading your extension from the extension management page, I remember once had a bug that my extension didn't reload, so I went to the developer's tools for my background page and executed window.location.reload(true); from console, that fixed it. Please respond if this worked, I will keep researching.

Comment: Reloading the extension fixed the getBackgroundPage() = null problem. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please repost your comment as an answer (the part about reloading your extension) so I can mark it as an Answer? I just read here that is what you're supposed to do: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer

Comment: The `background` permission has nothing to do with the way the extension works. This permission is to run continuously the extension in background from the start of the user session.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another answer with more options:

[chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() returns null after awhile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921500/chrome-extension-getbackgroundpage-returns-null-after-awhile)

> According to the referenced page (Difference between Event and
>   Background Page) there is a better option to get the background while
>   still using Event Page :
>
> If your extension uses, extension.getBackgroundPage, switch to 
>   runtime.getBackgroundPage instead. The newer method is asynchronous so
>   that it can start the event page if necessary before returning it.

Comment: While true, this is a very, very old question that has to do with manifest version 1, before Event pages were a thing.

Comment: Times may have changed, but helped me get on the right track!