# How do you modularize your Chrome Applications with Browserify?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browserify

I watched the following [Google Apps Office video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkb_x9ZN0Vo) and learned how you can use browserify to package your JS into one file using the node CommonJS packaging system. I like this idea as it also adds many node libraries ported to the browser and it can handle CoffeeScript.

The one thing the video did not cover was how to make a Chrome App that has more then one view still use browserify in a *DRY* way. Let me explain. Normally your browserify command takes a series of JS files (designed as modules) and concatenates it into a single JS file with some packaging sugar. This is great of you reference that JS file from say your content page, background page, or popup page. However, if you were to have an app that has both a background page **and** a popup page would you include the same compiled JS file in each? Would this not cause chrome to load the script twice (in two instances)? If so that seems like a lot of waste interpreting everything only to get the parts you want. Or is the require()/exports modal prevent unnecessary interpretation of modules you may not need for a particular context?

If this is not the best practise how should one package modules in a way that each *page* gets the needed modules in a dry way without having to repeat yourself or having separate browserify bundles per page? How have others approached this topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A technique that I've found works well is to create a separate bundle for each context (e.g. background, content, etc.). Here's an example directory structure:

```
.
├── extension
│   ├── js
│   └── manifest.json
├── lib
│   ├── background
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── content
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── frame
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── models
│       │   └── ...
│       └── views
│           └── ...
└── package.json
```

Inside the `lib` directory, create a folder for each context with `index.js` as the entry point. This file will bootstrap the application for that particular context, `require`ing whichever modules and initializing that part of the app.

Then use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify) to create the bundles in `./extension/js/`:

```
$ browserify ./lib/background/index.js -o ./extension/js/background.js
$ browserify ./lib/content/index.js -o ./extension/js/content.js
$ browserify ./lib/frame/index.js -o ./extension/js/frame.js
```

If you intend to reuse the same module in, say, `background.js` and `content.js`, just `require()` it in each context and browserify will build the bundles accordingly.

This process can be streamlined by using a [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/christophercliff/chrx/blob/master/examples/basic/Gruntfile.js) or [custom npm script](https://github.com/christophercliff/chrx/blob/master/examples/basic/package.json#L6).

You can try a working example of this approach [here](https://github.com/christophercliff/chrx/tree/master/examples/basic).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I think this helps me understand the relationship between chrome extension requirements and browserify. My next chrome project will probably take this format.

Comment: I'm also curious, How did you input the line art into the textarea above? was this a feature of an external editor?

Comment: I've made the experience that this doesn't work in all cases. For example, the syntastic suger that browserify add around `background.js` makes it impossible to properly access variables from `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`. Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 4):

In the case of multiple entry pages and one monolithic JS script the idea would be to encapsulate your JS logic in such a way that your background.html or background script will expose needed functions/objects to the global (read window) context. Then in other entry pages such as options or a popup you use this to get access to the background page's global context:

```
Application = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().myGlobalFunction();
```

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971566/chrome-extension-getbackgroundpage-returns-null-why) offers some insight to the layout and interplay.

That allows you to have one version of the browserify created JS and yet allow it to communicate / execute on other pages of the same extension.

Answer (score 2):

Libraries like Browserify are typically designed to support 'single page web applications'. That is, there's typically only a single HTML file involved in the application (usually public/index.html), which simply serves as an entry point that loads the hard dependencies (such as the concatenated output of browserify). Everything else is managed by Javascript, and whichever front-end framework you opt for (i.e. Backbone, SpineJS, etc).

While a single page web app might contain multiple 'screens' of data, the actual HTML for these pages are typically fragments of html (often using a javascript templating middleware such as Handlebars, Moustache, ECO, etc), loaded via AJAX, and then inserted into the running body of the page. That is - these new page fragments already have access to the javascript previously loaded in this page.

So you are being DRY with a SPA because you only have one page, therefore you aren't repeating yourself with JS imports.

If you're previously used to full-stack web development where a large part of UI is rendered by a server-side language, the idea of a single-page web application can be a bit of a shock. While most SPA tend to have a server-side component, this is typically reduced to a RESTful API providing data endpoints (that the AJAX calls will hit) and persistence.

Comment: Excellent explanation. The question was focus on Google Chrome extensions which by nature have more then one entry point. The background.html, the popup.html, and the options.html. With browserify you have one JS file. And I think I just answered my own question...

Comment: It's also worth noting that in the latest (2.4+) builds of Browserify you can actually have multiple generated JS files using the -r flag. If you require('foo') and foo.js isn't built into the current generated source it will look for it in other modules in the page. In other words, I could have a base bundle where I browserify all of my shared code, and individual browserify bundles for page-specific modules. That, combined with your answer below, could give you a nicely modular extension. Source maps are another matter entirely, though :/

Answer (score 0):

Under windows 10 I used `MKLINK` to share my source script(js) and style(css) files across projects

```
MKLINK /J "D:\Projects\Chrome Extension Projects\myproject\shared" "D:\Projects\Chrome Extension Projects\shared"
```

Comment: For using MKLINK refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx