# chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() returns null after awhile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, null

When my chrome extension loads on chrome startup, everything seems to be ok and chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() returns the right value (lunched from popup.js). But after awhile (2-3 minutes), especially if the browser is let alone, the function returns null. Only closing and re-opening chrome solves the problem.
I tried to manipulate it by:

```
if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() == null) window.location.reload(true);
```

As suggested at [Why does chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971566/chrome-extension-getbackgroundpage-returns-null-why), which sometimes helps, but most of the times it just keeps refreshing the app so that chrome must be closed.
Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you post more of the code or at least part of the code context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the referenced page ([Difference between Event and Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)) there is a better option to get the background while still using Event Page :

> If your extension uses, extension.getBackgroundPage, switch to 
>   runtime.getBackgroundPage instead. The newer method is asynchronous so that
>   it can start the event page if necessary before returning it.

This worked well for me, just do your job in the asynchronous callback, which receives the background page as a function parameter.

Here is the specification of the method [runtime.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage)

Comment: You should reformat the citation with the character `>` in front of it instead of 4 spaces!

Answer (score 3):

Change your background(Event Page) to a real background Page.

Modify your manifest file from

```
"background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    }
```

**to**

```
"background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    }
```

Event pages are very similar to background pages, with one important difference: event pages are loaded only when they are needed. When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources.

## Reference

- [Difference between Event and Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)

Comment: Note that event pages are preferred over so-called "real" background pages. From reference link you posted: ["Event pages are available in the stable channel as of Chrome 22, and the performance advantages are significant, especially on low-power devices. Please prefer them to persistent background pages whenever possible for new development and begin migrating existing background pages to this new model."](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)