# has no method getBackgroundPage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn about chrome extensions, and I think I am missing something. I want to upload a file using background script...here is my manifest:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "myTest",
"description": "Upload file",
"version": "0.1",
"icons": {
    "64": "64.png",
    "16": "16.png",
    "32": "32.png",
    "128": "128.png"
},
"background":{
    "scripts": ["justupload.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://my.url/page.html"],
      "js": ["link.js"]
    }
  ],
"permissions": [
    "http://my.url/page.html","background"
]
```

And link.js

```
function sendbg(){
var BGPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
BGPage.senddata(document.getElementById('files'));
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', sendbg, false);
```

When files changes, I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getBackgroundPage'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication via content scripts needs to be done with message parsing.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921500/chrome-extension-getbackgroundpage-returns-null-after-awhile) and [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)